# In **portable C**, how to launch a command connecting the command's stdin to the launcher's stdout?

Tags: c, ipc, pipe, portability

In a C program (p1), how to launch a dynamically constructed command (and its arguments) that reads its standard input from p1's standard output?

Note that:

1. A method other than this stdout -->
   stdin piping is also OK **provided**
   it is **PORTABLE** across Windows and
   Linux.
2. I cannot use C++, Java, Perl, Ruby,
   Python, etc here.

Also, will this have a MinGW dependency for its Windows build?

**REOPENED**: The question below answers it for Linux, but this question wants a portable method.
[Execute program from within a C program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70842/execute-program-from-within-a-c-program)

Comment: Note that, I would prefer a C solution only. (Sorry for the incovenience!)

Answer (score 4):

The Microsoft C runtime calls it [`_popen`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/96ayss4b.aspx) instead of [`popen`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/popen), but it appears to have the same functionality in Windows (for console applications) and Linux.

Answer (score 2):

It's not 100% clear to me what you're trying to achieve exactly to be honest.

But as I understand it, you could take a look at [Boost.Process](http://www.netbsd.org/~jmmv/process/)

You can do things like

```
 bp::child cs = p.start();
 bp::postream& os = cs.get_stdin();
```

And then use the *os* as any stream to dump stuff in the standard input of your child process.

Anyway, an awful lot can be achieved with the library w.r.t. pipe redirecting and chaining.

Comment: Hmm, boost. An 800-pound gorilla that I will need to link and shake hands with. I will still be watching out for any overall lightweight, C responses. Thanks, though. (Note that I'm now dropping the C++ from the condition.)

Answer (score 1):

The linked anser (which you reject) refers to POSIX pipes. POSIX is an extension to C, which adds features missing from standard C. POSIX pipes are a good example of such a feature: they were added to POSIX because standard C does not have that functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The glib library is written in C and has implementations that are well tested on both Linux and Windows.  [The manual section on spawning new processes](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Spawning-Processes.html) will give you information about how to start a new process and hook into its stdin and stdout handles using the **g_spawn_async_with_pipes** call.