# How to execute bash commands from C?

Tags: bash, c, gzip

Is there a way to run command line utilities, e.g. `gzip`, into a C app?

Comment: why not just use the c library for (de)compression (zlib)?

Comment: If you run it as a "bash command", a la system(), you're doing it wrong. Direct invocation with an exec-family syscall is more efficient and less prone to bugs.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Use [`system()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/system/):

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int status = system("gzip foo");
```

See the man page (`man 3 system`) for more detailed information on how to use it.

By the way, this question already has an answer here: [How do I execute external program within C code in linux with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237482/how-do-i-execute-external-program-within-c-code-in-linux-with-arguments)

Comment: See: [**Why to avoid system() function in c/c++**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19913446/why-to-avoid-system-function-in-c-c). Instead look at the `execl` family of functions.

Comment: `man system` # seems to default to 3

Comment: No entry for system in section 1 of the manual
No entry for system in section 2 of the manual
so starts at 3