# How can I recursively search for all files in given directories in C?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that can search for all the files in given directories and store them in an array. I have an array "spaths" that contains a list of paths to the directories that need to be searched for files. I would like to store the paths of all the files in another array called "files".

I have a basic plan of how this could work:

```
while (elements in spath[]!=0){
      files[].append(files in spath[0]);
      spath[].append(directories in spath[0]);
      spath[0].delete;
}
```

(Note: The above code is not real code, it's just a code-looking representation of how I would want the code to work.)

I am using Windows 11 with VS Code as my editor and `MinGW-W64 x86_64-ucrt-posix-seh` with `gcc 13.2.0`.

I found many solutions using `dirent.h` but I tried and found out that including `dirent.h` causes conflicts with VS Code, however it is compilable. Whenever I try to use `dirent.h` in my code, I get this in VS Code:

```
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\Dibakar\Desktop\C\Ivory X\Source\ivory-x.c).C/C++(1696) cannot open source file
```

And yes, this happened with just a singular `#include <dirent.h>` line, and this is not just a VS Code issue, it won't let me compile either.

I later found out that `Windows.h` is a good replacement option for Windows machines. However, I could not find any recursive searching code using `Windows.h`. Even popolar AIs like ChatGPT and Gemini could not help me as their code did not work. I have found a few solutions on StackOverflow to this question but I could not really understand what the code given in the answers did and hense had problems implementing it in my code. If anyone can provide me code with an in-depth explanation then I will be greatly helped.

Any help on this topic will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "Even popolar AIs like ChatGPT..." have no clue about programming and are not suitable to be used as learning material.

Comment: If you show us how your current attempt looks, we can see where you went in wrong direction.

Comment: "found out that installing dirent.h in Windows is very complicated" It is not. You install MinGW, and dirent.h comes with it. End of story.

Comment: From your question it is not clear for me what you want to get as a result. Do you want to find all files in that folder **including subfolders** or only in that folder alone? Why do you want to use recursion? Searching files in a single folder is 100% not a recursive task and using recursion will not make your task easier.

Comment: @Gerhardh I know that those AIs have no clue about programming but I wanted a quick result so I tried them. It does not matter anyways cuz I did not get the solution that I wanted. I want to find all files in that folder including subfolders. I have a idea for a basic recursive loop that does that but not sure how to implement it. This is what I got so far:
while (elements in spath[]!=0){
      files[].append(files in spath[0]);
      spath[].append(directories in spath[0]);
      spath[0].delete;
}
I have added this plan to the body of the question too with some better formatting.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI Not happening. Whenever I try to use dirent.h in my program, I get this:
`
#include errors detected. Please update your includePath. Squiggles are disabled for this translation unit (C:\Users\Dibakar\Desktop\C\Ivory X\Source\ivory-x.c).C/C++(1696)
cannot open source file "dirent.h"C/C++(1696)
`

Comment: You have a messed VS Code install (like 99% of beginners). Ditch VS Code, compile from the command line.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI nah, compiling from command line also doing the same result. The compilation is failing.

Comment: Doesn't happen here. How did you install the compiler? It is usually recommended to install Msys2 and from there install any of the compiler flavours and additional tools you want. (I have 4 compilers installed, every one of them comes with `dirent.h`)

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI I downloaded the compiler, added it to the C drive and added it to that path variables. But wait. Nah, I can compile it. But it is overlaying it with squiggles. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: The problem with _"I could not really understand what the code given in the answers did"_ is that there are answers here on Stackoverflow that you know of but weren't enough. We can't however know what they were lacking, so anyone who might try to answer will probably reiterate what those answers told and therefore not be useful. Instead, include those answers in the question and explain what was insufficient.

Comment: I recommend going the Msys2 route, it is very robust, but whatever works for you.  On the VS Code front, you do need to edit your [c_cpp_properties.json](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/c-cpp-properties-schema-reference) and specify the correct includePath (it should explicitly include whatever include directory comes with the compiler).

Comment: `dirent.h` is some POSIX dinosaur stuff. In case of Windows there's the FindFirstFile/FindNextFile API calls. These can be used with a loop so that you avoid recursion, POSIX and other such bad practices.

Comment: "POSIX and other such bad practices" I want a T-shirt.

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI The T-shirt printer used `getline` and got severe memory leaks I'm afraid. We forked them over to another process where the leaks are handled with pthreads. As soon as we join them, you'll get a core dump printed on an indeterminate number of T-shirts - would that be ok? They'll be size 11 SIGSEGV, excellent to crash in.

Comment: If VS code shows squiggly lines, that does not directly affect compilation. That is just the editor which is not able to find the file.

Comment: @Gerhardh I understand that, but how can I fix it

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI This is my c_cpp_properties.json:
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Win32",
            "includePath": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/**"
            ],
            "defines": [
                "_DEBUG",
                "UNICODE",
                "_UNICODE"
            ],
            "windowsSdkVersion": "10.0.22621.0",
            "compilerPath": "cl.exe",
            "cStandard": "c17",
            "cppStandard": "c++17",
            "intelliSenseMode": "windows-msvc-x64"
        }
    ],
    "version": 4
}
Edits?

Comment: Your `c_cpp_properties.json` is set up to use Microsoft Visual C/C++ compiler, but you are trying to use gcc. Use [the official guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw) to set up VSCode with gcc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [FindFirstFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findfirstfilea), [FindNextFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findnextfilea), [FindClose](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-findclose) from Windows.h.

This shoud do the job:

```c
#include <Windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct DirectoryContent
{
    char **files; // array of all files in a specified directory (including subfolders)
    int nFiles;   // number of elements in `files`
    char **dirs;  // array of all directories in a specified directory (including subfolders)
    int nDirs;    // number of elements in `dirs`
};

typedef struct DirectoryContent DirectoryContent;

// Free resources allocated for `DirectoryContent` structure
void freeDirectoryContent(DirectoryContent *content)
{
    if (content == NULL)
        return;
    // free every filename
    for (int i = 0; i < content->nFiles; i++)
    {
        free(content->files[i]);
    }
    // free the array itself
    free(content->files);
    // free every directory name
    for (int i = 0; i < content->nDirs; i++)
    {
        free(content->dirs[i]);
    }
    // free the array itself
    free(content->dirs);
    // free the content
    free(content);
}

// Merge all contents from `second` to `first`. `second` is then freed
void mergeDirectoryContents(DirectoryContent *first, DirectoryContent *second)
{
    // reallocate memory for files
    first->files = (char **)realloc(first->files, (first->nFiles + second->nFiles) * sizeof(char *));
    for (int iFirst = first->nFiles, iSecond = 0; iSecond < second->nFiles; iFirst++, iSecond++)
    {
        first->files[iFirst] = second->files[iSecond];
    }
    first->nFiles += second->nFiles;
    free(second->files);
    // reallocate memory for dirs
    first->dirs = (char **)realloc(first->dirs, (first->nDirs + second->nDirs) * sizeof(char *));
    for (int iFirst = first->nDirs, iSecond = 0; iSecond < second->nDirs; iFirst++, iSecond++)
    {
        first->dirs[iFirst] = second->dirs[iSecond];
    }
    first->nDirs += second->nDirs;
    free(second->dirs);
    // free second directory content
    free(second);
}

// Test function for printing `DirectoryContent` contents to stdout
void printDirectoriesContents(DirectoryContent **contents, const char **spaths, int nPaths)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < nPaths; i++)
    {
        DirectoryContent *content = contents[i];
        printf("[%d]: %s\n", i, spaths[i]);
        if (content)
        {
            printf("\tFiles:\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < content->nFiles; j++)
            {
                printf("\t\t%s\n", content->files[j]);
            }
            printf("\tSubdirectories:\n");
            for (int j = 0; j < content->nDirs; j++)
            {
                printf("\t\t%s\n", content->dirs[j]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("\tNULL\n");
        }
    }
}

// The main function which returns filled `DirectoryContent` structure for the given directory `sdir`
DirectoryContent *getDirectoryContent(const char *sdir)
{
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fdFile; // a data about files we have found
    HANDLE hFind = NULL;    // a search handle

    // allocate 2048 characters just to be sure that every path is fits in here
    char spath[2048];

    // set a file mask. `*.*` means we search for all files
    sprintf(spath, "%s\\*.*", sdir);

    // start find process
    hFind = FindFirstFile(spath, &fdFile);
    if (hFind == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        printf("Path was not found: %s\n", sdir);
        return NULL;
    }

    DirectoryContent *content = (DirectoryContent *)malloc(sizeof(DirectoryContent));
    // default initialization
    content->files = NULL;
    content->nFiles = 0;
    content->dirs = NULL;
    content->nDirs = 0;
    do
    {
        // the first results are always "." and "..", so we just ignore them
        if (strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, ".") == 0 || strcmp(fdFile.cFileName, "..") == 0)
            continue;

        // put found filepath to `spath` by appending its filename to `sdir`
        sprintf(spath, "%s\\%s", sdir, fdFile.cFileName);

        // check if the filepath is a directory
        if (fdFile.dwFileAttributes & FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY)
        {
            // add directory to content
            content->nDirs++;
            content->dirs = (char **)realloc(content->dirs, content->nDirs * sizeof(char *));
            content->dirs[content->nDirs - 1] = (char *)malloc((strlen(spath) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(content->dirs[content->nDirs - 1], spath);
            // recursively find all files in the subdirectory
            DirectoryContent *subdirContent = getDirectoryContent(spath);
            mergeDirectoryContents(content, subdirContent);
        }
        else
        {
            // add file to content
            content->nFiles++;
            content->files = (char **)realloc(content->files, content->nFiles * sizeof(char *));
            content->files[content->nFiles - 1] = (char *)malloc((strlen(spath) + 1) * sizeof(char));
            strcpy(content->files[content->nFiles - 1], spath);
        }
    } while (FindNextFile(hFind, &fdFile)); // find next file

    FindClose(hFind); // end search process and clean resources
    return content;
}

// Fill array of `DirectoryContent` structures for every path in `spaths`
DirectoryContent **getDirectoriesContent(const char **spaths, int nPaths)
{
    DirectoryContent **contents = (DirectoryContent **)malloc(nPaths * sizeof(DirectoryContent *));
    for (int i = 0; i < nPaths; i++)
    {
        contents[i] = getDirectoryContent(spaths[i]);
    }
    return contents;
}

// Test it
int main()
{
    // specify here all paths you want
    const char *spaths[] = {"C:\\Users\\username\\foo",
                            "C:\\Users\\username\\foo\\foo",
                            "C:\\Users\\username\\bar",
                            "C:\\Users\\username\\foo\\foo\\Empty folder"};
    // specify here the number of paths
    int nPaths = 4;

    DirectoryContent **contents = getDirectoriesContent(spaths, nPaths);

    printDirectoriesContents(contents, spaths, nPaths);
    for (int i = 0; i < nPaths; i++)
    {
        freeDirectoryContent(contents[i]);
    }
    free(contents);

    return 0;
}
```

I've added a bunch of comments so it should be clear what code is doing. Anyway feel free to ask any questions.

Note, that in C it's a pure pain to mess with dynamic allocated arrays (and strings) - be extra carefull of memory leaks! Also it is unefficient to call `realloc` every time you appending an element. Better use C libraries that provide some kind of C++ `std::vector` functionality, but I'll leave this on your own (along with changing the code to support wchars).

Answer (score 0):

Since it seems you're not worried about cross-platform compatibility, and are just aiming for Windows functionality, you could consider using Command Prompt functions using `system()` ([Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29762190/18014565), [Man Pages](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/system.3.html)). Running `dir -s` (or, according to some [forums](https://superuser.com/a/32772/1843540), you might need to do `dir /s`) will list all files and folders recursively. You could then adjust this command to store it into a text file of your choice `dir -s > files.txt`, and then parse the new file using the rest of your C program. To make things easier on yourself, you can also add other flags onto the command to further reduce unnecessary info. The `-b` flag would likely be useful. See the documentation for the `dir` command [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/dir).

As for a more traditional approach, if you already know how to list all the files within a directory, as well as list all of the folders, you could implement the recursion yourself. Here's some pseudo code:

```
int recursiveList(string myDir, string[] files){
    files.append(getAllFilesInFolder());
    string[] subDirs = getAllSubFolders();
    if (subDirs.length > 0){
        //iterate through each subDir using a for loop
        recursiveList(subDirs[i], files);
    }
    //you're already overwriting the files variable, so no need to return it
    //just make sure files[] is big enough to hold everything
```

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanai referring to my command line approach? in which case I provided it because it can be called from a C program using `system()`. I understand the resistance to that since I probably shouldn't have strayed from pure C on this post. I'd be willing to edit my answer to better fit the spirit of the community on here if you think I should.

Comment: You should answer in the same language as used in the question. Answers in C++ to a C question (or vice versa) are off-topic.

Comment: Sorry didn't notice it's pseudocode.

Answer (score 0):

Below is an example that uses `dirent` and `Windows API` to scan a folder, recursively.

It is the same idea that is the pseudocode in the question

consider the folder `folder` as this

```
Stack Overflow> tree /f folder
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is 0000006F C062:8DEF
C:\FOLDER
│   quatro.sln
│   quatro.vcxproj
│   quatro.vcxproj.filters
│   quatro.vcxproj.user
│   Selector.c
│
└───other
    │   1quatro.sln
    │   1quatro.vcxproj
    │   1quatro.vcxproj.filters
    │   1quatro.vcxproj.user
    │   1Selector.c
    │
    └───inner
        └───other
                file.txt
```

### output of the example code

```
Using dirent

folder
folder/other
folder/other/1quatro.sln
folder/other/1quatro.vcxproj
folder/other/1quatro.vcxproj.filters
folder/other/1quatro.vcxproj.user
folder/other/1Selector.c
folder/other/inner
folder/other/inner/other
folder/other/inner/other/file.txt
folder/quatro.sln
folder/quatro.vcxproj
folder/quatro.vcxproj.filters
folder/quatro.vcxproj.user
folder/Selector.c

Using Windows API

folder
folder/other
folder/other/1quatro.sln
folder/other/1quatro.vcxproj
folder/other/1quatro.vcxproj.filters
folder/other/1quatro.vcxproj.user
folder/other/1Selector.c
folder/other/inner
folder/other/inner/other
folder/other/inner/other/file.txt
folder/quatro.sln
folder/quatro.vcxproj
folder/quatro.vcxproj.filters
folder/quatro.vcxproj.user
folder/Selector.c
```

### example code

```
#include <iso646.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>

#include "dirent.h"

int scan_dirent(const char* folder);
int scan_ffirst(const char*);

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    printf("\nUsing dirent\n\n");
    scan_dirent("folder");
    printf("\nUsing Windows API\n\n");
    scan_ffirst("folder");
    return 0;
}  // end main()

int scan_dirent(const char* target)
{
    DIR* pDir = opendir(target);
    if (pDir == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr, "\tCould not opendir(%s)\n", target);
        return -1;
    }  // end if
    if (strcmp(target, ".") == 0) return 0;
    printf("%s\n", target);
    struct dirent* Folder;
    struct _stat64 info = {0};
    while ((Folder = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
    {
        if (strcmp(Folder->d_name, ".") == 0) continue;
        if (strcmp(Folder->d_name, "..") == 0) continue;
        // ckeck: if is a folder check inside
        //  builds the filename
        char* path = malloc(
            2 + strlen(target) + strlen(Folder->d_name));
        if (path == NULL) return -1;
        sprintf(path, "%s/%s", target, Folder->d_name);
        int res = _stat64(path, &info);
        if (res != 0) return -2;
        if (S_ISDIR(info.st_mode))
            scan_dirent(path);
        else
            printf("%s\n", path);
        free(path);
    }  // end while
    closedir(pDir);
    return 0;
}

int scan_ffirst(const char* path)
{
    if (path == NULL) return -1;
    // build 'ffd' to start scanning
    printf("%s\n", path);
    size_t len  = strlen(path);
    char*            name = malloc(len + 3);
    if (name == 0) return -1;
    strcpy(name, path);
    name[len++] = '/';
    name[len++] = '*';
    name[len] = 0;
    WIN32_FIND_DATAA ffd;
    HANDLE           hFind = FindFirstFileA(name, &ffd);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind)
    {
        fprintf(
            stderr, "\tError on FindFirstFileA for '%s'\n", name);
        free(name);
        return -2;
    }
    do {  // inside folder
        if (not (ffd.dwFileAttributes &
              FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DIRECTORY))
        {
            printf("%s/%s\n", path,ffd.cFileName);
            continue;
        }
        if (strcmp(ffd.cFileName, ".") == 0) continue;
        if (strcmp(ffd.cFileName, "..") == 0) continue;
        if (strcmp(ffd.cFileName, path) == 0)
        {
            printf("%s\n", ffd.cFileName);
            continue;
        }
        // ckeck: if is a folder check inside
        //  builds the filename
        char* sub = malloc(
            2 + strlen(path) + strlen(ffd.cFileName));
        if (sub == NULL)
        {
            free(name);
            return -3;
        }
        sprintf(sub, "%s/%s", path, ffd.cFileName);
        scan_ffirst(sub);
        free(sub);
    }  // if()
    while (FindNextFileA(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
    FindClose(hFind);
    free(name);
    return 0;
}
```

- `scan_dirent` uses `dirent.h`
- `scan_ffirst` uses the **Windows API**