# A way to manage File System in C for Windows

Tags: c, windows

I want to make a file manager in C for Windows, i.e., modifying, deleting, copying, viewing files, directories along with permissions, but I can't find a header file or library that does it. All of them are in C++ (including the MSDN docs, eg. <filesystem>). I was wondering if anyone could help me. I just want basic NTFS file system.

Comment: Do you want to just access APIs in the OS, or to directly access NTFS drive (interpret and manipulate NTFS structure)?

Comment: I would prefer the API, i dont want to deal with hardware stuff.

Comment: Define ‘file manager’.

Comment: @user207421 modifying, deleting, copying, viewing files, directories along with permissions

Comment: You know it might be easier to learn just enough C++ to make use of the broader cross-platform filesystem support available such as C++17's `<filesystem>` than to learn the somewhat arcane Win32 API.

Comment: The MSDN examples are marked C++, but almost all of them compile also in C and run ok. Just load one you need in Visual Studio, with C extension and test...See [https://stackoverflow.com/a/78050957] for an example of using recursive calls in C to scan a folder, using the Windows API.

Answer (score 1):

The Windows C API is commonly referred to as the Win32 API (even for 64-bit Windows).  It is declared in its entirety by including windows.h, and since filesystem access is an OS service there is of course an API for that.  See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-management-functions for the Win32 filesystem API.

It is filesystem agnostic, and valid for both FAT and NTFS filesystems, and also network file shares.

For a broad overview of the Windows API, start from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/