# Creating a terminal command programmatically?

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, c++11, terminal

I hope this question is okay. Basically what I want to do is create a small program that, using the Ubuntu terminal, I could just call it and execute a command from any directory. For an easy example, something like `print Hello World` would simply print `Hello World` back out.
Any advice on how I could do this?

```
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    for (char letter : arv) {
        std::cout << letter;
    }
}
```

I think something like that would work, just a really simple program, but how could I get it to install a command that I could use anywhere?
I hope this makes sense, if I should elaborate on something, please let me know.
To explain why this is not a duplicate, I will elaborate a bit to say that I'm not asking how to call a command from the program. It has been partially answered that I can move my executable file to the `/usr/bin/` directory, which was helpful, however I am more-so curious on how I can do it so that if a user downloads and uses my program, they won't have to move the file to `/usr/bin/`, they can just download and have their global command.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I execute external program within C code in linux with arguments?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237482/how-do-i-execute-external-program-within-c-code-in-linux-with-arguments)

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, I don't want to call the command from the program, I want to call it from the terminal's command line. Like you would  call ls or gedit or something.

Comment: Then just put your executable somewhere in the path (/usr/bin, /usr/local/bin) or modify your user's path environment to include some directory inside your home directory.

Comment: Okay thanks, I get that part now, but how could I do it "automagically" so that if a user were to use my program they wouldn't need to do anything?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A command is just a program in one of the directories specified by the environment variable `PATH`.

Run `echo $PATH` to see the directories (separated by colons).

A user can "install" your program simply by copying it to any of those directories. Conventionally, `/usr/local/bin` is for programs installed outside of the package manager, but any one would work. They could also copy it to a new directory and add that directory to their `PATH`.

If you want it to happen "automatically", then you need to get the user to run a different program that does it for them.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is what I was looking for. If you don't mind me asking you to continue, how would someone add a directory to their `PATH`? I know how to do it in Windows, but I'm not so sure with Linux/Ubuntu. Thanks!

Comment: “A command is just a program in one of the directories specified by the environment variable PATH.” And has the executable bit set: if it does not have that bit set (with `chmod +x command-to-be-given-execute-permissions`), it doesn't matter if it is in the `PATH`.

Answer (score -1):

You need ti use alias command
http://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/set-command-aliases-linuxubuntudebian/
or move your script/bin to /bin/

Comment: How would I do this more user-intuitively? Like how when you install maven, you can call `mvn`. I would like it so if a user were to use my program, they would be able to just call a simple command to use it. Such as `print` in the example.

Comment: /bin is for core system executables. Not even package managers usually touch that.

Comment: @PSkocik Is `/usr/bin` or `/usr/local/bin` preferred?

Comment: `/usr/local/bin` is (for executables you want to share  with other users, otherwise just put it somewhere under ~, e.g., `~/.bin.` or `~/.local/bin/` and make sure you have that in your $PATH). `/usr/bin` if for packaged programs.