# Open/run another program from C and then close this program

Tags: c, windows, system, execv, execve

How to execute/open/run another program from C, and not block on this but let it run simultaneously. Then I want to to do some test like server/client and then if this has been done I want to just kill/close this program. I have read about

```
system() or execv()
```

But first seems to be blocking an waiting for results, second seems to work only on Linux? In the best case scenario I would like to have cross-platform or minimum MacOS/Windows/Linux(Ubuntu) working solution. I also need to shutdown this previously opened program when I don't need it any more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The POSIX way to do it (which maybe could be used in Windows too -- https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb463220.aspx ?) 
is to use a [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) + [exec*](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) combo:

You use [fork](http://linux.die.net/man/2/fork) to create a new process that copies the current process.
Your handle to that process is an **int** process identifier (*pid*):

```
int pid;

if (0 > (pid=fork()){
   perror("fork failed");
   return -1;
}
if (0 == pid){
   //CHILD PROCESS
   printf("I'm the child process, my pid is: %d\n", getpid());

}
//pid > 0 ==> PARENT PROCESS
puts ("I'm the parent process"); 
printf("The pid of the child I've just spawned is %d\n", pid);
```

To run an executable in the child process, use an [exec*](http://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) function to replace the current (e.g., the child's if you run it in the child) process image with a process image loaded from an executable file.

In the parent, you can then use the *pid* handle to [kill](http://linux.die.net/man/3/kill) the process (=ask it to terminate):

```
 kill(pid, SIGTERM);  //please terminate
```

and you can use [waitpid](http://linux.die.net/man/3/waitpid) to retrieve its exit status after it has terminated .

---

( [system](http://linux.die.net/man/3/system) internally uses `fork` + `execv` (it execs a shell) + `waitpid`. Because the `waitpid` part isn't separate in `system`, `system` makes you wait for the child process to finish.)

You'll probably also want to look into [dup2](http://linux.die.net/man/2/dup2) and [pipe](http://linux.die.net/man/2/pipe) or [socketpair](http://linux.die.net/man/2/socketpair) to set up a fildescriptor-based communication channel with the child process (there are other options such as shared memory, message queues, or signals if you only need very basic communication).

The manpages are a good resource on managing processes and IPC.

Comment: thx this helps a lot :) I think I will use it in the future but now I redesign my test to be simpler: 1. run test server on separate pthread 2. do shell cmd to echo this server with popen() 3. get cmd output and assert it is correct.

Answer (score 0):

> How to execute/open/run another program from C ?:

use `system`

> How not to block on it?

you have to implement multitasking, so use `fork` to create another processes or `pthread_create`
 to create another thread, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237482/how-do-i-execute-external-program-within-c-code-in-linux-with-arguments#14866371)

> I would like to have cross-platform or minimum macOS/Windows/Linux(Ubuntu) working solution.

`system` works on linux and windows but i don't have any ideas about the other platforms

Comment: ok thx but can I later close it?

Comment: @MichałZiobro, u're welcome, Any problem ?