# How to run a c++ executable file apart from my main execution

Tags: c++, c

I've got a compiled executable file called "starTracking", and I need to use another c++ program to run this file.
Right now I'm using:

```
system("./starTracking");
```

But I can't wait it to finish before calling it again, so I'd like it to run apart from my main program so I can call it several times without making my main program wait.
Could someone tell me if there's a way to do it?
I'd be so grateful :D

Comment: and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237482/how-do-i-execute-external-program-within-c-code-in-linux-with-arguments) for linux.

Answer (score 0):

> I need to use another c++ program to run this file

If running your C++ on Windows read up on this guide **[Creating Processes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682512.aspx)**.

> I can't wait it to finish before calling it again, so I'd like it to
>   run apart from my main program so I can call it several times without
>   making my main program wait.

That's what running a process will do. To send/receive data to and from the external program make sure you involve **stdin** and **stdout**. See this section of the guide: **[Creating a Child Process with Redirected Input and Output](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682499(v=vs.85).aspx)**.

Comment: `You must be running your C++ on either a Windows or Unix system` Why you'd think so?

Comment: Last time I checked I had to involve `Windows.h` to use `createProcess`. It is a Win32 API, isnt it?

Comment: It is, of course. But where in OP's question was `CreateProcess` even mentioned?

Comment: If OP knew about `CreateProcess` then their question wouldn't exist to need such a suggestion (as told in my answer). Think about it. Also, read their last paragraph again, doesn't it sound like `CreateProcess` is right? If I too was tracking stars I might want to query the running tool (process) with std in/out for regular feedback into my own code...