# Open an Xvfb server from C

Tags: c, x11, xvfb

I heard of this technology called Xvfb, which is used to create virtual X sessions. The command to do this is `Xvfb :1`, or replace `:1` with any display you like. My question is: how can I do this within a C program? I am aware of the `system()` function, but this is usually bad practice, and only works if a client has Xvfb installed. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I execute an external program within C code in Linux with arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237482/how-do-i-execute-an-external-program-within-c-code-in-linux-with-arguments)

Comment: `...and only works if a client has Xvfb installed.` -- **And running.**  I don't see how that happens without running the Xvfb executable.  The Internet says that `system()` is a bad practice because it is insecure, but it also says "favor an API if you have one."  Which you don't have, if Xvfb isn't running.