# How to use exce() pass a int and return

Tags: c, linux, fork

I got two int in `main.c`, want to pass those two values to `hello.c` to run it using `exce()`, and return to `main.c` to print it, how can I do that?

I try a lot of ways but it keep fail.

`main.c`

```
    
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    int staff_id = 0210;
    int staff_working_hours = 10;

    if(0 == pid)
    {
       int args[] = {staff_id, staff_working_hours, NULL};
       excev(" ./hello.c", args);

    }
    else
    {
        
        print(" "); //print here
      
    }

    return 0;
}
```

---

`hello.c`

```
int main()
{
    //not want to print here, want to print by main.c 
    printf("Hello Staff ID: %d \n", staff_id);
    printf("Your working hours is: %d \n", staff_working_hours);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: There is no `exec` in the code you show. Please [edit] and clarify. Also read this: [ask] and this: [mcve]. Show at least what you have tried.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237482/how-do-i-execute-an-external-program-within-c-code-in-linux-with-arguments

Comment: "I try a lot of ways but it keep fail." --> Post you code that shows your try with `exec()`.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica just add some of my failed work

Comment: So is it `exce()` (quesiton) or `excev()` (code).  Best to post true code.

Comment: Tip: save time.  Enable all warnings.  Faster good feedback than posting on SO.

Comment: Did you read the documentation of `excev`?

Comment: please read the first comment above: make a real [mcve] instead of typing dubious code like this. And if it's really `execv` why don't read the documentation of `execv`? Why pass an int array to it?

Comment: Note that the function is normally called `execv()` — the `excev()` you refer to is not standard.  Assuming that the function name is a typo, arguments are passed as an array of strings.  You must use the signature `int main(int argc, char **argv)` in the second program to access the arguments passed to it.  After the invocation of `execv()`, you should make sure your program reports an error and exits.  If `execv()` succeeds, it does not return; if it returns, it failed.

Comment: Also, remember that `argv[0]` is the name of the program.  Your `args` array has the wrong type (it should be `char *args[]`) and it doesn't specify the program name.  Often, it is appropriate to use `execv(args[0], args)` to execute the other command.  Yes, you will need to format the numbers as strings to pass them to the second program.

Comment: `./hello.c` probably isn't an executable file. Perhaps you meant  `./hello`?

Comment: @IanAbbott want to call hello.c to input the value

Comment: @lemmonlola you cannot "call" a .c file with `exec` family of funtions. You only cann "call" executables (IOW compiled programs).

Answer (score 1):

You can not pass a `int` array to `execv()` and expect a well defined behaviour. `execv()` expects a list of strings. What you need to do first is  convert them to strings, or an array of strings. Something like `sprintf()` or since you are on Linux `asprintf()` could help you with that.
Also, you can't execute `hello.c` directly, you first need to compile it and execute the compiled program.
For example:

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE      //Needed for asprintf()
#include <stdio.h>

... //Some more code here

char command[] = "./hello";
char *nargs[4] = {command};
if(asprintf(&nargs[1],"%i",staff_id)<0) 
  { perror("asprintf"); exit(1); }
if(asprintf(&nargs[2],"%i",staff_working_hours)<0) 
  { perror("asprintf"); exit(1); }
excev(command, nargs);
perror("excv");
exit(1);
```

After that, you get the arguments in hello as strings, not as integers, you first have to convert them back to a `int` if you want to use them as `int`. For that `strtol()` could be helpful.

Note: I didn't free the memory allocated by `asprintf()`, here i don't need to because the program not continue to run, but don't forget that when you use `asprintf()` somewhere else.